# Reusing calculations in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to simplify this sql query? Lots of calculations are reused and it would be nice to name each expression and use the name instead of the full expression.

```
SELECT SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) As price,
 (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) - (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) * (T3.discount / 100))) As base_price, 
 ((SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) - (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) * (T3.discount / 100))) * (T3.vat / 100)) As vat_amount,
 (((SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) - (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) * (T3.discount / 100))) * (T3.vat / 100)) + (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) - (SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) * (T3.discount / 100)))) As total_price
```

I'm looking for a solution similar to this:

```
 SELECT SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) As price,
 (price - (price * (T3.discount / 100))) As base_price, 
 (base_price) * (T3.vat / 100)) As vat_amount,
 (vat_amount) + (base_price) As total_price
```

Comment: You can use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Create a view with your desired calculations.

Comment: Also you may use user-defined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing it with CTE's and subqueries as suggested but it ended up looking pretty complicated and undreadable so I decided to just do the calculations outside of sql (php in this case)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like that:

```
select 
(A.price - (A.price * B.p_discount)) As base_price, 
((A.price - (A.price * B.p_discount)) * B.p_vat) As vat_amount,
(((A.price - (A.price * B.p_discount)) * B.p_vat) + (A.price - (A.price * B.p_discount))) As total_price
from 
    ( select SUM(T2.price * T1.amount) As price, ...
    from T1 join T2 on ....
    ) A
join 
    (select (T3.discount / 100) as p_discount , (T3.vat / 100) as p_vat ,* 
    from T3
    ) B on ...
```